# Building a GlassFish RPM with latest updates?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, packaging, rpm

To make software deployment more reliable and easier it's a good idea to use the operating system's package management to distribute the software. Now I want to package GlassFish as RPM.

Goals:
- build once, deploy multiple times
- package GlassFish with latest updates
- package customized GlassFish with addons (neccessary for the application that should run on that GlassFish) (see note 1)

I already build a .spec fle which unpacks the GlassFish .zip (from Oracle) and packages it into a RPM.
Then I've tried to add a %build section that will run the pkg tool. 
The problem lies in GlassFish's update management: it only accepts to update to the recent version as you can not pass a version to update to (or can you?).

With this it's not possible to build a GlassFish RPM of a specific version from scratch again and again without having differnet results each time (in scales of weeks/months). So this approach is not usable to generate RPMs.

- How could I do this?
- Is this the completely wrong approach to package GlassFish as RPM?
- Which alternative distribution/packaging method would you recommend?

Note 1: I would favour to package such additional libaries (addons) as another RPM which depends on the basic GlassFish RPM but I don't think this is possible as there are too many files being touched when installing an addon.

Maybe I should change this question to "alternative way of distributing GlassFish", as so far, I can't see that it's possible to do I as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the right way to create generic GlassFish RPMs as it requires to remove the package manager and so makes it impossible to add necessary runtime libraries after installation (without packaging all GlassFish libraries as RPMs too).

The only useful approach using GlassFish RPMs is for application specific GlassFish installations containing all necessary libraries (and maybe configurations).

I would not use this as it add too much extra effort for too small benefit.

I continue with building check and setup scripts, checking the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I create a GlassFish installation tar that has the Linux native installer with an answer file and any patches or configuration changes needed. I then have an RPM scriplet which is built into an RPM. Inside the scriptlet I have commands to run the native installer with the location of the JDK and answer file (-a option). In my case, I run the remove weak ciphers command with a list of ciphers, disable http2 and then make any necessary environment changes.